# Angular 10 model class decorator?

Tags: angular

I recently upgraded my project from Angular 9 to Angular 10, and now adding a decorator to classes is mandatory.
I have a model class that has no **decorator**. It's also a TypeScript file.

Let's say I have the following model

```
export class Car {
   model: string;
   type: string;
   year: string;
}
```

Now when I run `ng serve`, it throws that the class has a missing decorator. It's not a component, nor a directive.

Specific error is the following:

```
NG2007: Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.

12 export class Car {
                ~~~~~~~
```

It even complains about classes that I use later on to be extended in some of my components. Forces me to use decorator every time.

How can I handle this issue?

Comment: @Igor yes, sorry! Adding it.

Comment: Where and how is `Car` used in the code? Is it derived from at all or used in other type definitions that are angular framework specific?

Comment: Question is, in Angular 10, what If i have parent classes with functionality that I simply want to extend later on in any of my components? That's what I have now, but it's complaining due to the missing decorator, but it's just a parent classes, not abstract, because i have implementations and everything, but It simply lacks of any decorator, is not an angular class, just typescript.

Comment: The only thing I can find that is somewhat relevant is https://v10.angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes but based on what you have stated the type `Car` does not fall in to that category. I would try to create an [mcve] and include it with a bug submission on https://github.com/angular/angular/issues

Comment: K, thanks @Igor i will check that out.

Comment: If your class injected somewhere, then you might use `@Injectable()` decorator

Comment: Yea, not injected but one of my exported classes can be extended in a component. I found that there's an empty "Directive()" for this type of cases where it is a base class. And it worked!

Comment: Here's the reference: https://angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes#im-a-library-author-should-i-add-the-directive-decorator-to-base-classes

Answer (score 2):

According to the official docs, there's a way to handle these situations with base classes and stuff, is to add an empty Directive() decorator.

Here's the [reference](https://angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes#im-a-library-author-should-i-add-the-directive-decorator-to-base-classes).

I made it work this way, and no complaints during ng serve now.